# Function type vs Closure type

Tags: closures, rust

I want to create a vector of functions

```
let all_rerankers =  vec![ match_full
                         , match_partial
                         , match_regex
                         , match_camel_case
                         ];
```

However, `match_camel_case` needs one more parameter than other functions, so I though I could define a closure for `match_camel_case`

```
// 3 is the extra parameter needed by match_camel_case
let close_camel_case = |str: &str, keyword: &str| {
    match_camel_case(str, keyword, 3) 
};
```

and then specify the type of my vector:

```
let all_rerankers: Vec<|str: &str, kwd: &str| -> MatchScore>
    = vec![ match_full
          , match_partial
          , match_regex
          , close_camel_case
          ];
```

However compiling it shows me that Rust treats them differently:

```
mismatched types: expected `fn(&str, &str) -> MatchScore`, 
found `|&str, &str| -> MatchScore` 
(expected extern fn, found fn)

close_camel_case
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(and similar type error in my `vec!` macro)

It also seem to distinguish between `Fn` type and closure type. I can make this compile by wrapping every `match_*` function in a closure, but I'm sure there's a better solution.

**Question:**

1. What is the actual mismatch here? the error message seems to suggest `Fn` vs closure type, but then there's also `expected extern fn, found fn` in the error message
2. How can I make the type match? (namely, convert closure into `fn` type, since it's pure)

my rustc version: `rustc 0.12.0-pre-nightly (09cebc25a 2014-09-07 00:31:28 +0000)` (can upgrade if needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like some unfortunate problem in type inference. If you do this:

```
let mut all_rerankers: Vec<|str: &str, kwd: &str| -> MatchScore> = Vec::new();
all_rerankers.push(match_full);
all_rerankers.push(match_partial);
all_rerankers.push(match_regex);
all_rerankers.push(close_camel_case);
```

Then everything is fine. The duplication is extensive, but you can easily write a macro whose invocation could look like this:

```
push_to!(all_rerankers;
    match_full,
    match_partial,
    match_regex,
    close_camel_case
)
```

This probably deserves creating an issue in [Rust bug tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues), but old closures will be deprecated soon, so I'm not sure if this is worth fixing.

Comment: That's not really a problem. It's like pushing 3 elements of some type X to a vector and then expecting the vector to change to some more general type Y. If no type is given, the type inferred is the first one added to Vec. And this is the case here.